# Using the interface TypedHash

Tags: typescript

I'm new. To JavaScript, TypeScript, etc.

I'm trying to use the SharePoint sp-pnp-js library to [add to a list](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/wiki/Working-With:-Items). The add method requires a type TypedHash - and the interface for it is:

```
export interface TypedHash<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}
```

And my code is:

```
import pnp, { ItemAddResult } from "sp-pnp-js";
import { TypedHash } from "sp-pnp-js";

// let listItemEntityTypeName: string = "undefined";
let body: string = `Title: 'Joe needs help'`;
let body2: string = `,'joe2': 'help2'`;
let body3: string = `,'joe3': 'help3'`;
let body4: string = `,'joe4': 'help4'`;
if (body2) {
    body = body.concat(body2);
}
if (body3) {
    body = body.concat(body3);
}
if (body4) {
    body = body.concat(body4);
    console.log("body4");
}
body = JSON.stringify({body});
let theTypeHash: TypedHash<string> = 


console.log(body);
console.log(typeof body);

pnp.sp.web.lists.getByTitle(`MyList`).items.add(theTypeHash)
    .then((iar: ItemAddResult) => {
        console.log(iar);
    });
```

I don't know how to use that interface to get the `body: string` into `theTypeHash`.

Thank you kindly.

Comment: First of all, there is no need to _use_ the interface directly, anything that has the same structure implements it by definition. Anyway, `TypedHash<T>` is any type that has properties whose values are `T`s. So just write `const theTypeHash: TypedHash<string> = {body: body};` or more simply, `const theTypeHash = {body};`.

Comment: Thanks Aluan! That did it: it did not give me a type error. But I don't get it -- why is `body` the **type**? I know I'm probably missing something fundamental.

Comment: it's not the type, it's the value actually